# Programatically set background (drawable) doesn't center

Tags: android, background, background-image, drawable, centering

I wrote an app that lets people select an image (drawable) and after they hit the "set as background" button the selected image should appear **centered** as the background of my phone.

Following code used to work fine. The image was placed and **centered**. But for operating systems (> api 13) it is depreciated. Does anyone know how to fix so that the image is also centered (or scaled to fit the screen if you wish)?

I've tried replacing it with "displaymetrics" or "points" to get w or h but it doesn't help centering the image. Is it the "suggestDesiredDimensions" that doesn't do it anymore?

ResID is the identifier of the needed drawable.

Anyone knows how to handle this? Thanks!

```
public void setBackground(View v)
{

    try {
        // Set background from a resource


        WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setResource(resID);

        WallpaperManager wm = (WallpaperManager) getSystemService(WALLPAPER_SERVICE);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int w = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
        int h = display.getHeight(); //deprecated

        wm.suggestDesiredDimensions(w, h);


    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using display.getSize()

```
public void setBackground(View v){

try {
    // Set background from a resource


    WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setResource(resID);

    WallpaperManager wm = (WallpaperManager) getSystemService(WALLPAPER_SERVICE);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    int w = size.x;
    int h = size.y;

    wm.suggestDesiredDimensions(w, h);


} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}